# Do two HTTPS POST calls on a single client - Java to Vb.Net

Tags: java, vb.net, post, https

I need to perform a login with HTTPS POST call into a site and after that do another POST call to perform an action.

I have written a method to perform this tasks in Java but now I need to switch my application in VB.NET and I can't use the JVM, java classes or similar.

This is my methods:

```
private static void disableSslVerification() {
try{
    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
    } };

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    // Create all-trusting host name verifier
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // Install the all-trusting host verifier
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (KeyManagementException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(to avoid the ssl verification)

and

```
public static boolean httpsPostCall(){
disableSslVerification();
HttpsURLConnection con = null;
String query = "username="+URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8"); 
query += "&";
query += "password="+URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8");
String query2 = "username="+URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8"); 
query2 += "&";
query2 += "project="+URLEncoder.encode("prog","UTF-8");
query2 += "&";
query2 += "area="+URLEncoder.encode("area","UTF-8");
query2 += "&";
query2 += "system="+URLEncoder.encode("system","UTF-8");
try{
    URL HTTPSurl = new URL("https://1.2.3.4/Login");
    con = (HttpsURLConnection)HTTPSurl.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length())); 
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)"); 
    con.setDoOutput(true); 
    con.setDoInput(true); 
    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());  
    output.writeBytes(query);
    output.close();
    //I use the same cookies to use the same login session
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // find the cookies in the response header from the first request
    List<String> cookies = con.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
    if (cookies != null)
        for (String cookie : cookies){
            if (sb.length() > 0)
                sb.append("; ");
            // only want the first part of the cookie header that has the value
            String value = cookie.split(";")[0];
            sb.append(value);
        }
    // build request cookie header to send on all subsequent requests
    String cookieHeader = sb.toString();

    // with the cookie header your session should be preserved
    URL regUrl = new URL("https://1.2.3.4/MethodAfterLogin");
    HttpsURLConnection regCon = (HttpsURLConnection)regUrl.openConnection();
    regCon.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieHeader);

    regCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
    regCon.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length())); 
    regCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    regCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0;Windows98;DigExt)"); 
    regCon.setDoOutput(true); 
    regCon.setDoInput(true); 
    DataOutputStream noutput = new DataOutputStream(regCon.getOutputStream());
    noutput.writeBytes(query2);
    noutput.close();
    DataInputStream ninput = new DataInputStream(regCon.getInputStream());
    String risp = "";
    for(int c = ninput.read(); c != -1; c = ninput.read()) 
        risp += (char)c;
    ninput.close();
    if(!risp.contains("New user activity created"))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Now I've tryed to find how to do this on VB.NET but I didn't fine any result. I've found only how to do a POST call with this code:

```
Dim url As New Uri("https://1.2.3.4/Login")
Dim content As HttpContent = New StringContent("{""username"":""" + login.username + """,""password"":""" + login.password + """}", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
Dim returnValue As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
Using client As New HttpClient
    client.BaseAddress = url
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))
    returnValue = client.PostAsync(url, content)
    MessageBox.Show(returnValue.Result.Content.ToString)
End Using
```

but when I perform the MessageBox.Show() method he gave me "System.AggregateException" error with the message "One or more errors occurred."

Anyone can give me a hand, please?

Comment: The AggregateException exception won't help you just like that. It's just a place holder for the actual exceptions. You'll need to check the Handle function or InnerExceptions property. Or turn on Break on All Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The error could be due to an unhandled exception. Wrap your web request code with a try/catch block

```
Try
    here put web request code

Catch wex As WebException
    If TypeOf wex.Response Is HttpWebResponse Then
        MsgBox(DirectCast(wex.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode)
    End If

    other web exception handling

Catch ex As Exception
    other exception handling

End Try
```

Also remember to put web requests on a thread different from the UI one to avoid blocking it

I use this code to make POSTs ad it always worked:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 'This is for enabling SSL/TLS support
mWebClient = New WebClient()

Dim reqparm As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
reqparm.Add("username", login.username)
reqparm.Add("password", login.password)

Dim responsebytes = mWebClient.UploadValues("https://1.2.3.4/Login", "POST", reqparm) '!!! I don't know if HTTPS is supported !!!
Dim risp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes)
```

Comment: I've put the try catch block on it but with debug I can see that the code go in the last catch, the general one and the ex.message is "One or more errors occurred."...

Comment: If I use this code to do an HTTPS call the exception tell me "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.".
Now I don't know if there's a possibility to install a fake truster like disableSslVerification method in java

Comment: What? why would you ever do such a thing?? Enable SSL/TLS support with this line `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3` Also edited answer

Comment: Because at the moment I didn't have a valid HTTPS certificate on this site :/
If I go on this link with chrome they tell me "There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID)"

Comment: This is not related to your question. You should post another one and close this since I think it is now solved